# BibTeX not compiling

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, natbib

On a recent document, I could not get the BibTeX file to compile and populate my citations and references.  The log returned an error, which I attempted to fix by changing the encoding of my .bib file, and moving it to the parent director.  Neither of these fixes were successful.

Below is the code and warning message

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\title{Judicial Resonsiveness to Other Branches and the Public}
\author{xxx}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\doublespacing

Hello world \citep{Gely1990}

\bibliographystyle{apsr}
\newpage
\singlespacing
\bibliography{POLSlibrary3.bib}
\end{document}
```

This is the error:

```
"This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) The top-level auxiliary file: GARseparation.aux The style file: apsr.bst I couldn't open database file POLSlibrary3.bib.bib ---line 4 of file GARseparation.aux : \bibdata{POLSlibrary3.bib : } I'm skipping whatever remains of this command I found no database files---while reading file GARseparation.aux Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Gely1990" (There were 2 error messages)"
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Update, just moving things from my replies to the original documentation.

```
@ARTICLE{Gely1990, author = {Rafael Gely and Pablo T. Spiller}, title = {A Rational Choice Theory of Supreme Court Statutory Decisions with Applications to the 'State Farm' and 'Grove City' Cases}, journal = {Journal of Law, Economics, and Organization}, year = {1990}, volume = {6}, pages = {263-30}, owner = {Phillip}, timestamp = {2013.11.11} }

 @BOOK{Watson1969, title = {The Politics of The Bench and The Bar: Judicial Selection Under the Missouri Nonpartisan Court Plan}, publisher = {Wiley and Sons}, year = {1969}, author = {Richard A. Watson and Rondal G. Downing}, address = {New York}, owner = {Phillip}, timestamp = {2013.11.24} }
```

Comment: Use `\bibliography{POLSlibrary3}` i.e. no extension `.bib`

Comment: BTW, Welcome to the site :-)

Comment: Thanks @Harish, but removing the extension did not work `This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) The top-level auxiliary file: GARmissouri.aux The style file: apsr.bst I couldn't open database file POLSlibrary3.bib ---line 5 of file GARmissouri.aux : \bibdata{POLSlibrary3 : } I'm skipping whatever remains of this command I found no database files---while reading file GARmissouri.aux Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Watson1969" (There were 2 error messages)`

Comment: You have to put the `POLSlibrary3.bib` in the same folder as your `GARmissouri.tex file. How do you compile using bibtex? Can you post your bib file?

Comment: I moved the `POLSlibrary3` file to the parent folder after the error first occurred about two weeks ago, thinking that was the cause of my problem.  Since I have several projects that work off the same bib file, I store it in a documentation folder and specify the pathname in the `\bibliography{}` command.

I am using Texmaker.  To compile, I PDFlatex 3x, BibTeX 3x, and PDFlatex 3x.

Comment: Does the bib file contain an entry for `Watson1969`?

Comment: First the wronge database name, then the database not found, no clear information. After updating, the wrong file endding in `bibliography` still remains. Fixing this, everything runs ok. I VtC as unclear.